# FME: why do my readers sometimes not get added to the canvas?

Tags: fme-form

Sometimes when I generate a workspace in fme 2014, the reader and writer get created but not added to the workspace. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What FME License Level are you using?

Comment: I have a Evaluation on my mac, but a pro licence at work

Comment: What format is your input (Reader?) and Output (Writer)

Comment: I´ve just tried it with a SHP to SHP...nothing else. The writer is created and is appears in the Navigator window but is not in the workspace canvas. I can´t drag and drop it either, and no context menu??

Comment: Cannot re-create this on Window 7 Pro, maybe a bug?

Comment: It's the same issue with Oracle writer and reader.  We need specified the dB user name. For shapefile check with the FME support

Answer (score 5):

The obvious problems (and apologies if these really are too obvious)

- Your datasets are empty!
- There is a problem scanning the schema. Check the log window for errors
- You are trying to read a dataset with the wrong format set (e.g. it is a Shape dataset but the format is set to MapInfo)
- That part of the canvas is just not in view!

You could try reading the data with the FME Data Inspector, as this would confirm whether there is a problem with the data or not.

Anyway, I've seen this happen, but only on very rare occasions. If the problem persists you should definitely contact the support team.